# Bold letters although the bold font weight is not imported

Tags: html, css

I am importing two weights (`300` and `400`) of a font with Google Fonts in my CSS and declare some classes to use them. For this example I will use the font **Yanone Kaffeesatz**. I would expect I could then only use these two weights of this font. But somehow it possible to also get bold text, or with the weight 700. This seems to be the case for all fonts and I can't understand what is going on.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:300,400&display=swap');
p {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.light {
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* This should be impossible, right?  */

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Regular
</p>

<p class="light">
  Light. This makes sense, it is imported.
</p>

<p class="bold">
  Bold. But why?
</p>
```

Or a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/xs40m5o2/11/)

Where are those letters with `font-weight: 700` coming from?

Comment: You're seeing the browser's approximation of what that font would look like in that weight. The browser doesn't actually load that specific weight and there are often subtle differences between what the real weight looks like and what the browser's approximation looks like.

Comment: If browser does not find corresponding font for corresponding font-weight, it tries to render it with the specified weight by its own render mechanisms